# Android Factory reset programatically and skip setup wizard

Tags: android

Is it possible to Factory reset the device programatically(`with DevicePolicyManager wipeData()`) and skip the Setup Wizard after restart?

Used code:

```
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mDPM.wipeData(0);
```

UPDATE:
I need at least to simplify the Setup Wizard, if there is no way to skip it.Any ideas?

Maybe there is a way, using adb... 
UPDATE:
I can't do it with adb, in that state after factory reset, adb doesn't recognise the phone so I can't run any command through it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option is to use Intent.ACTION_MASTER_CLEAR. You need to have android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR permission for your app  to do this.

Comment: How can I use this with Device Policy Manager?